# An Azure function works from Postman but not from web browser and javascript

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a C# Azure function that manipulates an image file and returns a . Following is the complete code.

```
[FunctionName("ImageHandler")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetHandledImage([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            int CaseID = Convert.ToInt32(req.Query["CaseID"]);
            int ImageID = Convert.ToInt32(req.Query["ImageID"]);
            int ApplyAngle = Convert.ToInt32(req.Query["RotationAngle"]);
            string ImagePath = req.Query["ImagePath"].ToString();

            string ImageServer = "https://localhost:44331/training/Images";

            string FullImagePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", ImageServer, ImagePath);
            string Format = "";
            MemoryStream ms;

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageData = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(FullImagePath));

                using (var BitmapStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
                {
                    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(BitmapStream);
                    ImageFormat ImageFormat = b.RawFormat;

                    b = RotateImage(b, ApplyAngle, true);

                    using (ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png))
                        {
                            Format = "image/png";
                            b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                        }

                        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg))
                        {
                            Format = "image/jpg";
                            b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), Format);
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that this function works ok when invoked from Postman but not from my own code. Also, I am hosting the function on http://localhost:7001/api/

Following is my local.settings.json file:

```
    {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "EmailScheduleTriggerTime": "0 0 */6 * * *",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "SqlConnectionString": "***",
    "URL": "*****"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what I could do so I can this function from my browser too.

I am getting HTTP 404 error when accessing from my browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Your function is defined to accept only the `post` request. From browser if  you are hitting the URL directly by address bar then it would be http get call instead of post.

Comment: Yes this was the case. I had to mark it as "get".